# Avoiding ArcGIS Online limitation on number of records/features per shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-online, limitations

I know that to publish a shapefile to ArcGIS Online you must zip the shapefile and it must contain a maximum of 250 records.

I have a shapefile with 32,000 records.

How do I divide this into 250 records per shapefile?

---

*Original Question (prior to Google translation and touch up above)*

So che per pubblicare uno shape su arcgis online si deve zippare lo shape ed esso deve contenere 250 record massimo...
Io ho uno shape con 32000 record...come faccio a suddividere tutti questi record a 250 per volta?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to edit your question to indicate whether you are comfortable with uploading and using a minimum of 120 shapefiles to/on ArcGIS Online?  Also, can you let us know whether you already have any GIS software that you might be able to use to manipulate shapefiles?

Comment: importare singolo shapefile 32000 record su arcgis online?E' possibile?

Answer (score 2):

I just researched any limitation on shapefile size for uploading to ArcGIS Online and found an [FAQ:  Is there a feature limit in ArcGIS Online?](http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/42465) which does not confirm the limit of 250 that you describe.

That FAQ says:

> By default, there is a limit of 1,000 features when uploading a file
>   (shapefile or CSV file) to a web map on ArcGIS Online.
>
> ...
>
> To upload a file beyond the feature limit set by ArcGIS Online, use
>   feature services. Feature services are a more scalable way to publish
>   features as it supports vector feature querying, visualization, and
>   editing.